# Select data from text fields in table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as below;

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" name="qwer"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" name="asddf"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" name="zxcv"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" name="poiu"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lkjh"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"> <button id="BUT">BUT</button> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The middle cells contain text fields with names. I want to get data (I think `.val()`) from specific input fields. How can I get them? Say I want to alert value we enter in input `name="zxcv"`.

You can see my [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/5nbwJ/).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('#mytable input[name=zxcv]').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate on input fields, and show "name" and "value" when "BUT" is clicked :

```
$("#BUT").click(function() {
    $("#mytable input").each(function() {
        alert("name : " + $(this).attr('name') + " - value : " + $(this).val());
    });
});
```